# Failed insert into database

Tags: php, html, sql, insert, isset

I've a problem with this code. I've this html form

```
<form method="post" action="invio_db1.php">
    Nome <input type="text" name="nome"> <br><br>
    Cognome <input name="cognome" type="text"> <br><br>

    <input value="Invia" type="submit">
    <input value="Reset" type="reset">
</form>
```

and this php code

```
<?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $nick = "root";
    $pw = "";
    $db_name = "associazydbe";

    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $nick, $pw) or die ("Errore nella connessione");
    mysqli_select_db($db, $db_name) or die (mysqli_error());

    if(!empty($_POST["nome"]))
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    else
        $nome = null;

    if(!empty($_POST['cognome']))
        $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    else
        $cognome = null;

    $query = "INSERT INTO persons_comeunprodigio (nome, cognome)
                  VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome')";

    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

I think it hasn't error but, after the running, in the database, all fields are null!
I can't find and fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do `echo $query;` just before you attempt to insert it, just so you can see if the query is properly formed?

Comment: Also make sure your database has columns the exact same as the ones you've specified and make sure they accept the appropriate data type

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: localhost doesn't map to 127.0.0.1 on every machine, so its better to use localhost rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: You also need to use `mysqli_error($db)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should add condition to your PHP script and insert data into database only when you send the form.

Instead of:

```
   if(!empty($_POST["nome"]))
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    else
        $nome = null;

    if(!empty($_POST['cognome']))
        $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    else
        $cognome = null;

    $query = "INSERT INTO persons_comeunprodigio (nome, cognome)
                  VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome')";

    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

you should have:

```
if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {

   if(!empty($_POST["nome"]))
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    else
        $nome = null;

    if(!empty($_POST['cognome']))
        $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    else
        $cognome = null;

    $query = "INSERT INTO persons_comeunprodigio (nome, cognome)
                  VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome')";

    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Now you need to fill in form and press submit button to insert data to database.

However you should use at least `mysqli_real_escape_string` but better choice would be [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). At the moment your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.